# Maximum daily rep

Tags: support

Am I right that the maximum daily reputation has increased since graduation from 200 to 200+ ? Or is the daily rep a reflection of what it *could* have been and is it still capped to 200 and is the messaging of capping been abandoned?

Comment: I presume that this still applies ?http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it Reputation farming are you :) ?

Comment: @RoverEye - I thought so too, but previously it would give me a 'warning' and now it doesn't. Plus, the Meta post is quite dated. last response was 2013? Maybe it changed?

Comment: @RoverEye - mmm farming yes, mining no :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum daily reputation is still capped at 200 per/day plus acceptance reputation plus bounties you receive on that day. For example you got 4 of your answers accepted, so your maximum daily reputation for today will be 260 (unless you have more answers accepted or receive bounties).

Comment: Ahaaaa, so it increases with accepted answers! That's why. I noticed the same yesterday , but now you mention, I got quite a few answers accepted then too. Thanks a lot!